# How to implement LSTM with Spark?

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, apache-spark

I would like to build an `LSTM` network for text classification with `PySpark`, but I don't find any library or function about it.

Is it possible to implement this kind of network in `Spark`?

Answer (score 2):

Apache Spark currently has no Deep Learning libraries. However, you can run TensorFlow models on clusters. According to [this article](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/01/25/deep-learning-with-apache-spark-and-tensorflow.html) "The TensorFlow library can be installed on Spark clusters as a regular Python library".

Additionally, I just found the [SparkFlow](https://medium.com/lifeomic/sparkflow-train-tensorflow-models-with-apache-spark-pipelines-74dca32f60f3) module, that should be meant to interface Spark and TensorFlow. The GitHub repo is [here](https://github.com/lifeomic/sparkflow).